# Tetrabonacci series in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, fibonacci

I have been racking my brain over this all weekend and cannot seem to figure out this last part. I am to write an assembly program to calculate the nth number in the tetrabonacci series. For example:

```
     n |0|1|2|3|4|5 |6 |7 |
output |1|1|2|4|8|15|29|56|
```

The `n` is sent from a C++ (which I have already wrote). The assembly program accepts the n entry and pushes it into the stack decrements the number and adds (up to) the last 4 prior numbers. My code works except that it does not work, it is a number off when I enter any number above 4. For example when I enter 4 it outputs 8 correctly but when I enter 5 it outputs 16 instead of 15 and 6 outputs 32 instead of 29 like it should. If you can assist I would greatly appreciate it.

Below is my code:

```
TITLE Tetrabonacci Series

.586
.model flat,C

.code

Tetrabonacci PROC
    push       ebp
    mov        ebp, esp
    push       ebx
    sub        esp, 4
    mov        eax, [ebp+8]
    cmp        eax, 0
    ja         L1            
    mov        eax, 1
    jmp        done

L1:
    cmp        eax, 1
    ja         L2
    mov        eax, 1
    jmp        done

L2: 
    cmp        eax, 2
    ja         L3
    mov        eax, 2
    jmp        done

L3:
    cmp        eax, 3
    ja         L4
    mov        eax, 4
    jmp        done


L4:  
    dec        eax
    mov        [esp], eax
    call       Tetrabonacci
    mov        ebx, eax
    mov        eax, [ebp+8]
    dec        eax
    mov        [esp], eax
    call       Tetrabonacci
    lea        eax, [ebx+eax]

done: 
    add        esp, 4
    pop        ebx
    pop        ebp
    ret
Tetrabonacci ENDP
END
```

Comment: For those who don't know Tetrabonacci numbers is the series `F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + F(n - 3) + F(n - 4)`.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're calling the function only twice, passing the same argument (`n - 1`) both times.

Comment: So `F(n + 1) = 2 * F(n) - F(n - 4)`.

Comment: hmmm, I think i see so where 

dec eax 

occurs I need to decrement the eax based on the current iteration it is on? How can I dynamically know where I am in the iteration to do that?

Comment: Removed C++ tag. Please don't attach irrelevant tags. That you call the code from C++ is not part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the first commented formula you have to call the function **four** times and to add the four results. I corrected your code as little as possible:

```
...
L4:
    mov        [esp], eax           ; n for recursive call

    dec        DWORD PTR [esp]      ; n-1
    jc         @F                   ; finish if (n-x) < 0
    call       Tetrabonacci
    mov        ebx, eax

    dec        DWORD PTR [esp]      ; n-2
    jc         @F                   ; finish if (n-x) < 0
    call       Tetrabonacci
    add        ebx, eax

    dec        DWORD PTR [esp]      ; n-3
    jc         @F                   ; finish if (n-x) < 0
    call       Tetrabonacci
    add        ebx, eax

    dec        DWORD PTR [esp]      ; n-4
    jc         @F                   ; finish if (n-x) < 0
    call       Tetrabonacci
    add        ebx, eax

    @@:                             ; finish
    mov        eax, ebx

done:
...
```

Comment: This does EXACTLY what I expected it to do, I see where I erred I not only needed to call the function recursively as @molbdnilo suggested ( more than just the two times that I am ) but four times in addition I needed to decrement the n value each time through to add it. Thanks so much! This helps greatly!